# Git commit hashes for cachebusting scripts

Tags: html, git

I'm working at my portfolio, and I use Git for version control. Now I want to use the Git commit hashes for the cachebusting of images and CSS, JavaScript ala `image.jpg?923jjdf8e`

I thought it would be good to have a script which is executed after the commit which checks all files for vars like `{{/url/to/file.jpg}}`, than it replaces the the var by the url + hash.

The script would use `git log --format="%H" --max-count=1 README.md` to determine the hash.

Any ideas if there is already a script for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I think I don't really understand why you want to do this, but I think `git hash-object` is what you need to know the hash of an image.

The script you say should be executed **before** commit, I think, so the commit contains the modified version instead of the variable (or do you want to record the variable in the commit?).

Then, I think you can use a pre-commit hook (see your `REPO_BASE/.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample` as a base) where you do some `awk` magic, I think, in order to replace your variables with the output of applying `git hash-object` to that variable.

But, really - I don't see the benefit at all. Don't you forget that your objects may be packed in the repository, if you were attempting to save some disk space.

Comment: Thx for ur answer, i have a bare repo on my server and when i push stuff to the bare repo it is exported to an extra folder (webserver folder). In the Webserver Folder i want to manipulate the files, not in the git repo.